# Is Oracle Database Standard Edition Free?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, rdbms

I'm a beginner level RDBMS student. I need to manage and test SQL commands on one database on my laptop (localhost).
I see 'Oracle Database Standard Edition 12c' (2.6 Gb) in the [download section](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/index.html). So, is it free or does it need licensing?

Comment: I thought the free edition was called Oracle Express.  But, if you can download it, then it is probably free.  Whatever software you download, you'll probably need to sign a license agreement of some sort.

Comment: Just try to download it and then you will find out rest. Have fun, just ask the Oracle support team otherwise.

Comment: The problem is its more than 2 Gb, takes a whole day to download.

Comment: Since you don't seem to have a specific need for Oracle in particular, you would probably be better off downloading [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/).  It will be considerably smaller, and the implementation is definitely both free of charge and open-source.  PG is also pretty standards-compliant -- more so than Oracle on one or two key points.

Comment: The express edition is completely free.  The standard and enterprise editions are not free but are freely downloadable under the OTN license.  That is generally fine for things like mucking around to teach yourself Oracle.  It doesn't let you run production processes.  You'd need to review the license agreement (that comes up before you download) to see whether your intended use is compatible with the standard or enterprise edition.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing.

Comment: I agree with John Bollinger. If this is just for learning, go for Postgres

Comment: If you just want to run and save SQL statements and you have an Internet connection you don't need to install anything but can use http://livesql.oracle.com

Answer (score 5):

Oracle has a version called `Oracle Express` which is, in fact, free.

You can download it from here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/express-edition/overview/index.html

From its webpage:

> Oracle Database XE is a great starter database for:
>
> Developers working on Node.js, Python, PHP, Java, .NET, XML, and Open
>   Source applications
>
> DBAs who need a **free**, starter database for training and deployment

Comment: Link for Oracle Versions:   https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DBLIC/editions.htm#DBLIC109      Link for Oracle Prices:    http://www.oracle.com/us/corporate/pricing/technology-price-list-070617.pdf

Comment: It may be an idea about limits of the express (free) edition:
"Oracle Database XE can be installed on any size host machine with any number of CPUs (one database per machine), but XE will store up to 11GB of user data, use up to 1GB of memory, and use one CPU on the host machine."